# Effects of swapping buffers on concurrent access

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Consider an application with two threads, *Producer* and *Consumer*.

Both threads are running approximately equally frequent, multiple times in a second.

Both threads access the same memory region, where *Producer* writes to the memory, and *Consumer* reads the current chunk of data and does something with it, without invalidating the data.

A classical approach is this one:

```cs
int[] sharedData;

//Called frequently by thread Producer
void WriteValues(int[] data) 
{
    lock(sharedData) 
    {
        Array.Copy(data, sharedData, LENGTH);
    }
}

//Called frequently by thread Consumer
void WriteValues() 
{
    int[] data;

    lock(sharedData) 
    {
        Array.Copy(sharedData, data, LENGTH);
    }

    DoSomething(data);
}
```

If we assume that the `Array.Copy` takes time, this code would run slow, since Producer always has to wait for Consumer during copying and vice versa.

An approach to this problem would be to create two buffers, one which is accessed by the Consumer, and one which is written to by the Producer, and swap the buffers, as soon as writing has finished.

```cs
int[] frontBuffer;
int[] backBuffer;

//Called frequently by thread Producer
void WriteValues(int[] data) 
{
    lock(backBuffer) 
    {
        Array.Copy(data, backBuffer, LENGTH);

        int[] temp = frontBuffer;
        frontBuffer = backBuffer;
        backBuffer = temp;
    }
}

//Called frequently by thread Consumer
void WriteValues() 
{
    int[] data;

    int[] currentFrontBuffer = frontBuffer;

    lock(currentForntBuffer) 
    {
        Array.Copy(currentFrontBuffer , data, LENGTH);
    }

    DoSomething(currentForntBuffer );
}
```

Now, my questions:

1. Is locking, as shown in the 2nd example, safe? Or does the change of references introduce problems?
2. Will the code in the 2nd example execute faster than the code in the 1st example?
3. Are there any better methods to efficiently solve the problem described above?
4. Could there be a way to solve this problem without locks? (Even if I think it is impossible)

**Note**: this is no classical producer/consumer problem: It is possible for Consumer to read the values multiple times before Producer writes it again - the old data stays valid until Producer writes new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is locking, as shown in the 2nd example, safe? Or does the change of references introduce problems?

As far as I can tell, because reference assignment is atomic, this may be *safe* but not ideal. Because the `WriteValues()` method reads from `frontBuffer` without a lock or memory barrier forcing a cache refresh, there no guarantee that the variable will ever be updated with new values from main memory. There is then a potential to continuously read the stale, cached values of that instance from the local register or CPU cache. I'm unsure of whether the compiler/JIT might infer a cache refresh anyway based on the local variable, maybe somebody with more specific knowledge can speak to this area.

Even if the values aren't stale, you may also run into more contention than you would like. For example...

- Thread A calls `WriteValues()`
- Thread A takes a lock on the instance in `frontBuffer` and starts copying.
- Thread B calls `WriteValues(int[])`
- Thread B writes its data, moves the currently locked `frontBuffer` instance into `backBuffer`.
- Thread B calls `WriteValues(int[])`
- Thread B waits on the lock for `backBuffer` because Thread A still has it.

> Will the code in the 2nd example execute faster than the code in the 1st example?

I suggest that you profile it and find out. X being faster than Y only matters if Y is too slow for your particular needs, and you are the only one who knows what those are.

> Are there any better methods to efficiently solve the problem described above?

Yes. If you are using .Net 4 and above, there is a BlockingCollection type in System.Collections.Concurrent that models the Producer/Consumer pattern well. If you consistently read more than you write, or have multiple readers to very few writers, you may also want to consider the ReaderWriterLockSlim class. As a general rule of thumb, you should do as little within a lock as you can, which will also help to alleviate your time issue.

> Could there be a way to solve this problem without locks? (Even if I think it is impossible)

You might be able to, but I wouldn't suggest trying that unless you are extremely familiar with multi-threading, cache coherency, and potential compiler/JIT optimizations. Locking will most likely be fine for your situation and it will be *much* easier for you (and others reading your code) to reason about and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
First of all, I assure you that my question was hypothetical. I am aware of the benefits of correct locking and do not want to do bad things. 
However, I am curious about the statement that the code in the 2nd example is unsafe. Would you kindly tell me, where in the code and under which circumstances an unsafe operation could happen?

Comment: @Emiswelt Whoops, I looked at the code with Friday on the brain and didn't look carefully enough. I've updated my answer to address the issues that I see.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't thought about the refreshment issue you described.